# Flash loading swf causes multiple GET on same file on IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, actionscript-2

I have a flash application that loads swf from a remote server, many of these swf's are duplicates and for some reason requesting them dost trigger a cache load but keeps sending out GET to the server.

This can be seen on fiddler and only happens on IE and only occurs in same session, refreshing the page loads everything from cache.
note that I cannot prevent the duplicate swf calls cause as2 dosnt allow me to duplicate loaded content, I need to be able to load them from cache after they are loaded the first time.

Any idea why this is not being pulled from cache?(I have tried delaying sequential requests to even a 1 sec no go...)

Comment: Did you intend to provide some code? [quote]This can be seen on fiddler[/quote]

Comment: I have managed to figure out the cause of the issue, it appears that when i put an interval of 500ms between the first GET of a file and the GETS of that same file then IE gets it from cache. for some reason there seems to be a cache latency. I would provide code but its long and isn't the cause of the issue. IE cache is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out the cause of the issue, for some reason IE takes significantly longer to load swf files the FF&Chrome, for this reason the requests were getting sent out before the files actually get cached. I wonder why there is no mechanism to handle sequential requests.

Any way, waiting for the files to arrive before requesting them again triggers the cache.